# Why do I get 403 error in a directory that lacks index.html even with autoindex on

Tags: nginx, webserver

Here is some of the content of the `location` block of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`

```
location / {
  root /var/www/example.com/html;
  index index.html;
  autoindex on;
  autoindex_exact_size off;
}
```

So how do I stop http://example.com/some-directory-without-index-html-file/ from giving me a 403 error?

Contents of `/var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log` include this:

```
2020/08/22 22:41:45 [error] 3821#3821: *30539 directory index of "/var/www/example.com/html/my-directory/" is forbidden, client: 73.204.11.250, server: example.com, request: "GET /my-directory/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

Output of `nginx -T`

```
2020/08/23 23:04:08 [emerg] 89824#89824: open() "/etc/nginx/mime.types" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:18
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Line 18 is the "include" statement below...

```
http {
    include       mime.types; # This is line 18
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    # bunch of other nginx code below this...
}
```

Comment: Is there an entry in the error log?

Comment: @RichardSmith Edited my question to include output of an error log

Comment: Use: `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files. Check that you can see the `autoindex` statement. Is there any other `location` or `server` block that might be interfering? The `location` in your question looks fine **if** Nginx is selecting it to process the request.

Comment: @RichardSmith Updated question again. There are no other `location` or `server` blocks.